Spawn entity failed in WSL2. I am able to launch gazebo by itself though but not sure why this spawn entity failed
Hi I am trying to run the empty world launch file for the turtlebot3 on my WSL2 installation (running on ROS2 Humble). The issue I face is that the spawn entity seems to fail. I am not sure why this happens and would request for additional information. I have attached a copy of the error image.

